# Button switch in runtime

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

In android studio

i have 3 buttons. i want one button to be active for few seconds, the other two to be inactive and then random button should get activated for few seconds. the switch time should gradually reduce. the  entire process is for 2 mins.

the active button should get some specific color.

i don't seem to get the logic. If i get the code for this i 'll be happy.

i have the basic layout! The MainActivity is the default one!
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/Score"
    tools:text="0"
    android:minHeight="52dp"
    android:minWidth="52dp"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    tools:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:text="3 Point"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:elevation="14dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"/>

<Button
    android:text="2 Point"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Free Throw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to switch Button's visibility, you have to write your own 'Visibility manager', which turns buttons on and off by setVisibility(View.Visible) and  setVisibility(View.GONE). Databinding is a better way to do so, because you don't need to write your own logic for that.
Second, for timing interval use rxJava library, it has methods for generating sibgle event (Observable.timer(..)) and repetitive events (Observable.interval()).
Those events are run on background thread, so you have use finally .observeOn(AndroidSChedulers.mainThread()).
You should use this library, because it will be much more simplier, rather than inventing the wheel with Handler.postDelayed() method.
From your description, you should generate periodic events, say, every second and sum overall time. When that time exceed some threshold, you do some action.